# android: which wake_lock should we be using

Tags: android

The android documentation says that I should be using

> WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

instead of

> PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK. The link is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK)

But when I try to use it I get an exception saying it is an invalid lock level. I'm using API level 18, here is the code that fails.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, "My Tag");
```

Has anybody tried this? Does it work?

Comment: I think I just found the answer. I should be using the below code instead of using PowerManager for keeping the screen on "getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the API documentation one should be using the Window.addFlags() for keeping the screen on.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below is working fine, check this

```
import android.os.PowerManager;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    protected PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /* This code together with the one in onDestroy() 
         * will make the screen be always on until this Activity gets destroyed. */
        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        this.mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
        this.mWakeLock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.mWakeLock.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to give permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: thanks, but that's not what I was looking for. The lock level is deprecated. Please check my comment on the original question